# are readonly function on template slowing angular?

Tags: angular

let's say I have the following template

```
<div>{{myvalue.ID}}</div>
```

I can provide ID using

```
   public ID: string;
```

or

```
   get ID() {
      return this._ID;
   }
```

or even do something like

```
<div>{{myvalue.getID()}}</div>

readonly getID= (): string => this.ID;
```

which looks like a get actually.

My question is, compare to give a direct variable reference, are get and readonly function slowing angular ?

I have some variable I would like to display to the user, but keep them private cause I don't want anyone to modify them (in code and template). I believe there are no other way of doing so but, is it impacting performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not good design to use functions for binding references.

Few reasons for this are:

- A new reference to the function is created every time angular change detection (CD) runs. Since once returned the function reference is GC.
- Also, the function is called every time CD runs. This might not seem much for simple getter/setter functions. But can have significant impact if the function has more complex implementation. Eventually making CD heavy
- Any code between the interpolation syntax is evaluated as it is by Angular which results in the function call for CD cycle.

Comment: but how do you use a private variable in a template then ? Should I make everything public ? this will lower the maintainability tho as everyone can do whatever they want with all my variables.

Comment: You can always expose a simple `getter` function for the private variable. But usually by design, variables which need to be exposed in template should be public. Since post compilation the template is also converted to a class for performance.